# How to get date in specific locale with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, locale, utc

I need to get the date in a specific locale using JavaScript - not necessarily the user's locale. How can I do this?

I did some research and found `date.getUTCMonth()` and `date.getUTCDate()`. How can I use this or something else to get the date in a certain locale?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toLocaleDateString`:

From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString):

> The new locales and options arguments let applications specify the language whose formatting conventions should be used and allow to customize the behavior of the function.

```
const event = new Date();

const options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };

console.log(event.toLocaleDateString('de-DE', options));
```